# Safari displays black border around video

Tags: html, css, video, safari

I'm trying to "embed" a video in an image (in this case a video in a laptop graphic). I've set the image as bg and with padding I place the video in the "screen" area. Since this must be responsive, percentage-based paddings are in use.

```
.media > video {
  background-image: url(...);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  padding: 5% 15% 12%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/jerivas/pen/jqoVYj?editors=1100

It all works great... except in Safari. For some reason the video has a black border (sometimes all around, other times it's left/right or bottom/top). The video needs to blend seamlessly with the laptop, and this breaks the effect.

I have already trying recalculating padding, width, and height values with JS to only use integer px units, but the problem persists (this part is not in the pen).

Comment: I found this Stack Overflow post that may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849809/how-do-i-make-the-black-bars-on-the-side-of-an-html5-video-on-ipad-disappear

Comment: On my imac using safari 9.1 i don't see any border.